# Java: sensible classes

Tags: java, class, abstraction

I have a `Contact` class, the sole purpose of which, at the moment, is to have a name and address (which itself is split into a street and city). Should I:

A) Have name, street, and city fields in my `Contact` class, or

B) Have separate `Name` and`Address` classes and attach them to `Contact` with a composition relationship?

Currently I can see option A as justifiable because of the simplicity of the situation, but B also seems justifiable as extra operations could be added to `Name` and `Address` later without unnecessarily complicating the `Contact` abstraction. It also seems to make sense to group street and city data together in a more specific abstraction than just `Contact`.

The context for this is an exam question, so the focus is creating a small application with sensible classes.

Which option is better? Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Name is a person name I would go for separate class for Person with name, surname etc and then class for contact with street, postcode, email, number, phone.

If name is a name of the building on whatever related with contact details I would go for one Contact class with all the fields in it.

Answer (score 1):

The question is , what represents a name? Has behaviour? can't be represented just like a String?

You can make a class Contact and a class Person, person is the delegate in class Contact
for example

```
class Contact {

Person person;

public String getContactName(){
  return person.getContactName();
}
```

}